# Empirical bounds on $\left|\frac{\zeta'(1+it)}{\zeta(1+it)}\right|$

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, computational-number-theory

It is reasonable to expect that $$\left|\frac{\zeta'(1+it)}{\zeta(1+it)}\right| < 2 \log \log t$$
for all $t\geq 4$ (say): a somewhat stronger bound is known for $t\geq 10^{165}$ or so (Theorem 5 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2206.00819.pdf), and a quick verification shows the bound to hold for small $t$. Indeed, one should be able to run a Sage script using ARB (ball arithmetic - for the sake of rigor) on 128 cores for a few days to check that the bound holds for all $4< t< 10^6$, and that on its own is a convenient, useful bound to have for at least some practical purposes.

Can one do better? Because of https://arxiv.org/pdf/2311.16371.pdf , we cannot hope that $$\left|\frac{\zeta'(1+it)}{\zeta(1+it)}\right| < \log \log t$$ holds for all $t$: it is false for some very large $t$. One might hope for this inequality to be valid "in a reasonable range", analogously to, say, Mertens's conjecture, but in fact even that isn't the case: there are counterexamples with $t$ close to $4590$, with $t$ close to $30776$,  with $t$ close to $130060$, and probably also in a bunch of other cases.

It might seem reasonable to check for an inequality of the form
$$\left|\frac{\zeta'(1+it)}{\zeta(1+it)}\right| < \log \log t + c$$ for $C< t< 10^6$, even if know that any such inequality will be false for $t$ extremely large, or else an inequality of the form
$$\left|\frac{\zeta'(1+it)}{\zeta(1+it)}\right| < \log \log t + \log \log \log t + c$$ for $C< t< 10^6$, since such an inequality may be true for all $t$. The same goes for bounds on $\left|\frac{\zeta'(1-1/\log t+it)}{\zeta(1-1/\log t+it)}\right|$.

However - before I go burn a few tens of thousands of core-hours, I would like to know: what kind of computational results do people already have on these questions? Surely they must have been studied from a computational angle?

PS. Is anybody else having trouble getting the leq symbol to display correctly today?